# Insufficient Security with RabbitMQ 3.7.15 and Erlang 22.0.1 / 22.0.2 on centOS 7.6

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, centos7

Observing an Insufficient Security error after upgrading RabbitMQ server to 3.7.15 with Erlang 22.0.1 / 22.0.2 on centOS 7.6.

Initial State of system where SSL was found to be working:
CentOS Linux release - 7.5
RMQ - 3.7.7-1.el7
Erlang - 20.3.8.2-1.el7.x86_64

SSL was found to be working even when CentOS was upgraded to 7.6 and RMQ to 3.7.15. Checked after RMQ restart.
However when Erlang was upgraded to erlang-22.0.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm, SSL stopped working. (After RMQ restart)

RabbitMQ config:

```
[
  {rabbitmq_management,
  [{listener, [{port,     15671},
               {ssl,      true},
              {ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "<path>/cacert.pem"},
                          {certfile,   "<path>/cert.pem"},
                          {keyfile,    "<path>/key.pem"}]}
              ]}
  ]},

  {rabbit, [
     {log_levels, [{connection,info}]},
     {tcp_listeners, []},
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"<path>/all_cacerts.pem"},
                    {certfile,"<path>/cert.pem"},
                    {keyfile,"<path>/key.pem"},
                    {depth, 5},
                    {verify,verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]},
    {auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN','AMQPLAIN','EXTERNAL']},
    {loopback_users, []},
    {ssl_cert_login_from, common_name}
  ]}
].
```

RabbitMQ enabled pluggins:

[rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl,rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_shovel,rabbitmq_shovel_management].

Please help.

**Edit 1:**
Updated the rabbitmq.config in this manner. Cert based auth is working now.

```
[
      {rabbitmq_management,
      [{listener, [{port,     15671},
                   {ssl,      true},
                  {ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "<path>/cacert.pem"},
                              {certfile,   "<path>/cert.pem"},
                              {keyfile,    "<path>/key.pem"}]},
                              {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.3', 'tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1', 'tlsv1', 'sslv3']},
                              {ciphers, 
                                [{ecdhe_ecdsa,aes_256_gcm,aead,sha384}, {...}]}
                  ]}
      ]},

      {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.3', 'tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1', 'tlsv1', 'sslv3']},
      {rabbit, [
         {log_levels, [{connection,info}]},
         {tcp_listeners, [5672]},
         {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
         {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"<path>/all_cacerts.pem"},
                        {certfile,"<path>/cert.pem"},
                        {keyfile,"<path>/key.pem"},
                        {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.3', 'tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1', 'tlsv1', 'sslv3']},
                              {ciphers, 
                                [{ecdhe_ecdsa,aes_256_gcm,aead,sha384}, {...}]},
                        {depth, 5},
                        {verify,verify_peer},
                        {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]},
        {auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN','AMQPLAIN','EXTERNAL']},
        {loopback_users, []},
        {ssl_cert_login_from, common_name}
      ]}
    ].
```

However, shovels with amqps with port 5671 still error out.

```
[error] <0.7391.6> Shovel 'ShovelTest' failed to connect (URI: amqps://<ip>:5671/<blah>): {tls_alert,{insufficient_security,"received SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security"}}
```

Shovels work fine with ampq with port 5672 though.

Please help.

Comment: This is probably a cipher issue though you don't specify exactly what is giving the "insufficient security" error. Please see this guide - https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

Comment: @Luke,
Thanks for pointing me out to the troubleshooting page.

Added the necessary ciphers and TLS configs to the rabbitmq.config file.
Cert based auth is working now.
However in shovel management, amqps still gives insufficient security error. amqp works fine thought.

Comment: You have to add the ciphers to the configuration section for the shovel plugin as well.